# Detecting Numbers in a String Variable (In Java)

Tags: java, string, variables, java.util.scanner

So, normally for detecting user input, I use int and double variable types.

Example:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection;
    System.out.println("Welcome to RPG! (prototype name)\nIn this game, you do stuff.\nChoose a class:\n1. Soldier\n2. Knight\n3. Paladin\n4. Heavy");
    selection = in.nextInt();   
    if(selection == 1){
        System.out.print("you are a soldier");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print(selection);
    }
}
```

This technique usually works fine for me, but I noticed that if the user inputs a letter into the int variable, the game will crash because integers can't store letters. (right?) So I tried using a String variable in its place, like this:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String selection;
    System.out.println("Welcome to RPG! (prototype name)\nIn this game, you do stuff.\nChoose a class:\n1. Soldier\n2. Knight\n3. Paladin\n4. Heavy");
    selection = in.next();  
    if(selection == "1"){
        System.out.print("you are a soldier");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print(selection);
    }
}
```

This seemed to work at first, but as you can see, I have it set so that if the variable "selection" is equal to 1, that it will print "you are a soldier", yet this did not work, instead it printed out the "selection" variables value (1). Did I do something wrong or should I use a different type of variable?

Comment: _because integers can't store letters_ `int` uses 4 bytes, `char` uses 2. You have to do the whole conversion thing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something la this :

```
 try{
           int type = Integer.parseInt(selection);
           switch(type){
           case 1:{
            //do soldier stuff   
           }
           case 2:{
            // do knight stuff   
           }
           default:{
               //do other stuff
           }
           }
       }catch(NumberFormatException exc ){
           System.out.println(selection + "is not a number, try again!!!");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selection == "1"
```

Compare strings with `String#equals`.

```
"1".equals(selection)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. A quick point I'd like to make is if you're comparing strings you should use:

var.equals("string");

Since you're only taking one character you could use a character in which case the correct syntax would be:

var == '1'

If you want to be fancy you can do a try catch around your read statement and just read in an string and parse it to an integer, but that is a bit more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

change `selection == "1"` to `"1".equals(selection)`

Answer (score 0):

use .equals() for comparing the string "1" and selection and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) A simple explanation would be

`x == y` returns true only when both `x` and `y` refer to same object which is not in your case. equals check if contents are equal meaning if contents of memory location that `x` and `y` are referring to are equal or not.